# Como asignar nuevas columnas según los datos de una en especifica?

Tags: python, pandas

Según el siguiente dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""
id     Area     dia     resultado
2154821     hemo     2021-05-01    negativo
2154821     vih     2021-05-02    negativo
2154821     sifilis     2021-05-13    reactivo
2154821     creatinina     2021-05-14    negativo
2154821     vdrl     2021-05-15    reactivo
12345687     sifilis     2021-05-25    reactivo
12345687     creatinina     2021-05-26    negativo
12345687     vdrl     2021-05-27    reactivo
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+",  engine="python")
df
```

Se obtiene los siguientes resultados

```
id  Area    dia     resultado
2154821 hemo    2021-05-01  negativo
2154821 vih 2021-05-02  negativo
2154821 sifilis 2021-05-13  reactivo
2154821 creatinina  2021-05-14  negativo
2154821 vdrl    2021-05-15  reactivo
12345687    sifilis 2021-05-25  reactivo
12345687    creatinina  2021-05-26  negativo
12345687    vdrl    2021-05-27  reactivo
```

Pero se espera obtener columnas de este tipo según el examen asignándole solo la fecha y el resultado como el siguiente ejemplo.

```
id      sifilis     dia_sifilis     creatinina      dia_creatinina      vdrl        dia_vdrl        vih dia_vih hemo    dia_hemo
2154821 reactivo    13/05/2021  negativo    14/05/2021  reactivo    15/05/2021  negativo    2/05/2021   negativo    1/05/2021
12345687    reactivo    25/05/2021  negativo    26/05/2021  reactivo    27/05/2021
```

Alguna ayuda se los agradezco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es un [`pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
new_df = df.pivot(index='id',columns='Area', values=['resultado', 'dia'])
print(new_df)

         resultado                      ...         dia                        
Area     creatinina      hemo   sifilis  ...     sifilis        vdrl         vih
id                                       ...                                    
2154821    negativo  negativo  reactivo  ...  2021-05-13  2021-05-15  2021-05-02
12345687   negativo       NaN  reactivo  ...  2021-05-25  2021-05-27         NaN
```

Comentarios:

- `index` define el agrupamiento
- Con `columns` definimos la variable por la cual pivotear
- Con `values` establecemos los valores que se expandirán a lo ancho.